# Laravel validation resets inputs value

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am wondering how to pass to inputs old value if user fails the laravel validation. I've tried to use:
Example: `{{ Request::old('mail') }}`
And: `{{ old('mail') }}`
I think that if user fails laravel validation input values are deleted.
Anyone has some idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With laravel 5.2 If you’re redirecting back to the form, a really useful method is withInput():

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

This method has no parameters and what it does is saves the old form values into Session. Then in the form you can use function old($key) to retrieve those values for every field – that would be a separate topic about the Forms.

Comment: Thank you, but tell me please how I can redirect after fail validation? Where to set it? My sign up look like this: http://pastebin.com/p4qjW1jT. I mean is something in laravel that allows you to redirect after fail laravel validation? For example if(validator == false) or something like that.

Comment: $v = Validator::make($input, $rules);
if($v->passes())
{
    True
}
else
{false}

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this, if invalid

```
return Redirect::to('your_ulr')->withInput(Request::all());
```